# Background Overlay using Css

Tags: html, css, background, overlay, background-color

I’m trying to do a background overlay on top of my body but when i set the position to fixed, my page stops scrolling and i can’t move below. When i remove the fixed positioning, the overlay is only on some part of my page that is if i set the height to 100vh. When i scroll, the overlay stops.

This is what happens with 100vh height and no fixed positioning.
[image]

If i remove height: 100vh and use fixed positioning, I can't scroll anymore.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Movie Lovers Survey Form</title>
    <meta charset= "utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div> <h1 id="title">Movie Lovers Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us improve our platform</p>
    <form id="survey-form">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name <input type="text" required id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input></label>
        <label for="email" id="email-label"> Email <input type="email" required id="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter your email"></input></label>
        <label for="number" id="number-label"> Age <input type="number"  id="number" name="number" min="13" max="35"  placeholder="Age"></input></label>
        <label> What is your best movie Genre?  <select id="dropdown" required ><option value="0">Choose One</option>
          <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
        <option value="Action">Action</option>
        <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
        <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
        </select></label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <p>Which of these movie stars would you love to take a pic with?</p>
        <label> Jason Statham <input type="radio" id="Jason" value="Jason" name="hollywood"></input></label>
        <label> Ryan Reynolds <input type="radio" id="ryan" value="ryan" name="hollywood"></input></label>
        <label> Scarlett Johansson <input type="radio" id="scarlett" value="scarlett" name="hollywood"></input></label>

        <label> Which of these do you prefer?  <select id="dropdown" required ><option value="0">Choose One</option>
          <option value="Series">Series</option>
        <option value="Sitcom">Sitcom</option>
        <option value="Franchise">Franchise</option>
        </select></label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <p>Which of these movies have you watched? (Check all that apply)</p>
        <label> M3GAN <input type="checkbox"></input id="megan" value="megan"></label>
        <label> Hidden Strike <input type="checkbox" id="hidden" value="hidden"></input></label>
        <label> Barbie <input type="checkbox" id="barbie" value="barbie"></input></label>
         <label> The Little Mermaid <input type="checkbox" id="little" value="little"></input></label>
          <label> Oppenheimer <input type="checkbox" id="oppenheimer" value="oppenheimer"></input></label>

   <p>Which of these movie stars would you love to eat with?</p>
        <label> Tom Cruise <input type="radio" id="Tom" value="Tom" name="hollywood2"></input></label>
        <label> Zoe Saldana <input type="radio" id="Zoe" value="Zoe" name="hollywood2"></input></label>
        <label> Chris Evans <input type="radio" id="Chris" value="Chris" name="hollywood2"></input></label>

          <label><textarea rows="4" cols="30"></textarea></label>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" id="submit"></input>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background-image: url(https://www.movieloversmontana.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Movie-Lovers-Logo-Square.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
div{
  background-color: rgb(80,80,80,0.8);
 height: 100vh
 /* position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    right: 0;*/
  


}

form{
  width: 60vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1, #description{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
input{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use ` background-attachment: fixed;` on the body rules - https://jsfiddle.net/z7s2yqtj/

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry, just add this property to the body tag in CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

It should work. :)

Note: Don't use the position: fixed; etc.